# How to update the values in the table (SQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql, command-line-interface

I have two tables
Table 1

[image: table 1]

Table 2

[image: Table 2]

I need User_Name in table 2 to be updated with Name+Surname from Table 1.
I tried doing this with CONCAT, but it seems a wrong approach.

Any advice would be helpful

Comment: `CONCAT()` is definitely the right approach. Show what you tried.

Comment: What is the relationship between the two tables?

Comment: How the two tables are related? I mean what's the foreign key or similar attribute

Comment: While you might have two people named John Smith in the company, you wouldn't want them to have the same username. How will you handle duplicates?

Comment: Omg, I though the posted sample tables are in text (ascii table) format. I was wondering since when it's that fancy. Turns out those are images! Come on, please don't post them as images. Also you've mentioned that _"I tried doing this with CONCAT, but it seems a wrong approach"_ but you didn't include the query attempt in your question.